# String collection values duplicated when I save it then reload it from XML

Tags: c#, collections, xml-serialization, c#-2.0, propertygrid

Well I got very strange issue, when I fill a string collection in property grid with a value, then I save this to XML, when I reload the XML and check the string collection I find values are duplicated.

And this happen every time I save and reload.

Comment: could you please post the actual code?

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. All we can say at the moment is that there's probably a bug in the code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Not clearing the collection before loading?

Comment: And pick a version of the language or at the very least, don't pick a specific version.  Approaches in one version may not apply in another.

Comment: Thanks all, i ll try to post the code soon ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this how the issue is resolved :
in line 2: when i made _AttributesCustomList  private , the string collection is not dupplicated when i load the XML...
I really don't know why, but anyway the issue is solved ..

```
    [XmlElement("AttributesCustomList")]
    public list<string> _AttributesCustomList;
    [CategoryAttribute("Custom"), ReadOnly(false),
    Description("This property is customised to put new attributes")]
    //[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    [RulesCriteria("Custom AttributesList")]
    public list<string> AttributesCustomList
    {
        get { return _AttributesCustomList; }
        set { _AttributesCustomList = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code so I am going to *guess* the issue, As you describe you are serializing a string collection to xml file, but when you desirialize it, you noticed that the records are duplicated, this is common scenario when your collection have default values in the class at the first place, so when you deserialize it from xml, the xml serializer doesn't create a new string collection, instead it uses the method `Add` in the list and append the strings to your existing collection. example:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Foo
{
    private List<string> _myList = new List<string>(new string[] { "Some", "Data" });

    public List<string> MyList
    {
        get { _myList = value;}
        set { return _myList; }
    }

    public Foo() {}
}
```

In the previous class "`Foo`", if you create a new instance `Foo foo = new Foo();` and serialize it to xml, it will be serializing right, but when you deserialize it, you will find out that the collection items has been duplicated `"Some, Data, Some, Data"`.